# angularjs adds unsafe tag to image

Tags: angularjs

I'm retrieving an image from a database and when I display it as a base64 file, angular adds an unsafe tag to it. How can I fix this?
This is what I use

```
<img ng-src="data:image;base64,{{logo.base64}}" />
```

This is the result

```
<img  ng-src="data:image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhMUExMWFB=" src="unsafe:data:image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBx=">
```

If I remove the "unsafe" tag in the browser, the image displays fine.

Thanks.

Comment: What version are you using? A fix for this was pushed some months ago: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6581

Comment: Also look into `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`.

Comment: I added the code below but still doesn't work. I'm using AngularJs 1.2.22 $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist = /^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\//;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From your example, you don't need to change the white list. BTW if you have to set it, the `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` is a function so it should be set like this:

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\//);
```

For your problem, it is because your data URI doesn't match the regexp, a `/` after `data:image` is missing. It seems the image type is expected e.g. (`data:image/png;`).

Try adding the correct image type if it works or not, note that the `png` is just an example.

```
<img ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{logo.base64}}" />
```

Hope this helps.