# Getting “unsafe:” in extension on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an image :

```
<img data-ng-src="C:/var/vci/images/fleetImages/{{img.imageName}}" data-ng-type="{{img.imageType}}"/>
```

On html I am getting it as:

> unsafe:c:/var/vci/images/fleetImages/IMG_20150912_091552.jpg

I have added in app.js

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
     $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data):/);
}]);
```

but still I am getting same issue.
Help me fix this issue.

Comment: But why would you reference images directly from the disk like that, you probably have a webserver for that ?

Comment: I have saved images outside the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448580/angularjs-adds-unsafe-tag-to-image

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to whitelist the `file:` protocol.

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|file):/);
}]);
```

You should also consider using a relative path instead of a absolute local filesystem path.

Please see 
[Angular changes urls to "unsafe:" in extension page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606751/angular-changes-urls-to-unsafe-in-extension-page) and [unsafe link in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637133/unsafe-link-in-angular) for more info.

Comment: still getting same issue

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you currently have, or set up a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net)?